# GoogleAuthException: Unknown (android)when specifying correct clientID

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I am using the GoogleAuthUtil and PlusClient.

When I specify my client id as:

```
NNNNNNNNNNN-HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

it gives me GoogleAuthException: Unknown as the error. 
This is the clientId specified in the Google API Console.

When I specify my client id as:

```
NNNNNNNNNNN.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

it works? But this is not the clientId specified for my Android app?
When I try use this for OAuth the server fails to log in using this clientId.... So actually.. How do I resolve such a dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by just using the web id instead of android id which always gave me Auth Exceptions. hope this helps someone else solve this weird problem.